# Flink taskManager pod had too many thread named "pool-{xxx}-thread-1"

Tags: java, thread-safety, apache-flink, threadpool, flink-streaming

My flink job, taskManager vm has too many threadPool, every pool contains one thread, thread names:"pool-{poolNumber}-thread-1".

thread dump:

```
// about 2200 threads like this
"pool-236-thread-1" #153 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9e1c12d000 nid=0x245 waiting on condition [0x00007f9e40c66000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007a8082938> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

my debug:

1. I debug the job in my IDE, start the job.
2. there is one waiting thread names like 'pool-{poolNumber}-thread-1', which is "pool-5-thread-1".
3. I put a break on Thread.class's constructure.
4. the thread to create "pool-5-thread-1"'s stack is: [image]

questions:

1. I don't know what to do next

Comment: More info would help. Why is this a problem? What does your job graph look like, and how is the cluster configured? I'm trying to figure out if you just have a lot of tasks, in which case you are going to end up with a lot of threads. For example, if you want to have fewer threads per JVM, you could have more TMs with fewer slots per TM.

Comment: @DavidAnderson 1. there are too many threads(2k+) in my JVM, it shouldn't be that much. 2. job seems good, runs well. 3. there is only 4 operators in this flink job, one TM contains one slot which runs one parallelism, and one cluster contains one job. 4. another job(quit likely my job) contains about 40+ "pool-{poolNumber}-thread-1" threads, so I think my job has too many threads.

Comment: This isn't normal. To debug this, it would be helpful to know if these threads are all present when the job begins, or if the number is growing as the job runs. It seems likely that something you are doing is leaking threads.

Are you doing something in your code to create threads? For example, if you are using Flink's async i/o operator, the problem could be in there.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks for response(●'◡'●). 1. I don't use Flink async operator. 2. these threads are growing as the job runs, because I dump many times, the number of thread pool is growing as time and the{poolNumber}s are growing too. and stable at 2.2k.  3. I think those thread pool are rpc aimed pools, I am using arthas to analysis this thread leaking. I think before we got savepoint oom question was caused by this.